# the Desktop notification display time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the Notification API to the Notification in desktop, but it seems display too short time , can I config the time in the browser or have option in API ?

Comment: no you cannot.but you can show it multiple times .

Comment: What's "unclear or not useful" about this question?

Comment: @FastSnail Hi, just want to support  in chrome and Firefox . It seems have effect in Chrome when  i add a option in api like that
var notification = new Notification('Hello Notification',{ body:"This will not disappear!",requireInteraction:true});
but it haven't effect in Firefox , do you have any idea ? thanks a lot